# SQL Server Select statement with (XLOCK,READPAST)

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-deadlocks

I ran the following query and my records are locked now I can't read or update or delete. For testing purpose i didn't called commit tran and now these records got stuck. How can I release these locks which are already placed.

```
  BEGIN TRAN

  SELECT * from inquiry with (XLOCK,READPAST)  where inquiry_id=228563
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find you lock process id by sys.dm_tran_locks and kill it manually

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE = ‘OBJECT’
```

and then use KILL with id number

Comment: @Faisalkhan No, you should kill the session, so you have to use REQUEST_SESSION_ID